# Convert char chunks to stream

Tags: c++, stl, stream, iostream

I have an interface that produces chunks of data:

```cpp
void next(unsigned char* buf, size_t len);
```

I want to convert these chunks into a stream/queue. std::queue would work, but I would like to be able to read/write multiple characters at a time and also not do memory allocations for every single character. Something like stringstream/streambuf looked promising at first, but I need to keep an eye on memory consumption and could not figure out how to drop read characters from those streams. Since I don't need to be able to seek backwards, I would like characters that have been read to be removed from the underlying buffer.

Something roughly equivalent to a pipe in bash or a channel in Go would do.

Is there an STL class that can do that?

Comment: You could just write the bytes to the end of a `std::string` or `std::stringstream`, and then extract chars from that as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Deque would work. You can write multiple characters at a time thus:

```
std::deque<char> q;
const char *p;
int len; 
// [p, p+len) are the characters to be appended to the end of the deque
q.insert(q.end(), p, p + len);
```

Comment: You are right, the underlying container structure of deque allows for effortless writing of arrays of char. Reading an arbitrary sized chunk back from the deque is not a one-liner unfortunately, though. I guess I am searching for a socket-like structure, that can be used with fread and the like.